# intercepts in spanning regression

Tags: regression, asset-pricing, fama-french

what does a negative and a positive intercept imply in spanning regression or factor redundancy test? For example, value factor is regressed on the mkt, smb, rmw, and cma and the intercept is negative and insignificant. What will be the interpretation of this intercept in connection with the set of other factors?